# Calling a default constructor in a constructor argument

Tags: c++

I have a class `A` with a default constructor and a class `B` with a constructor that takes an object of class `A` as sole argument.

As a natural way to Create an object of class `B` I would consider

```
B b(A());
```

But the compiler interprets this as a function declaration.

I know that

```
B b((A()));
```

or

```
B b {A()};
```

are alternatives. But my question is: How can the first version be interpreted as a function declaration? From my point of view it doesn't look like one.

Comment: Ok, it's a duplicate. However it is quite hard to find out that the other two questions are related to this issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How can the first version be interpreted as a function declaration?

It's just a language rule: In C++ *everything that **can** be interpreted* as a declaration ***will*** be interpreted as a such.

---

The following code:

```
B b(A());
```

**can** be interpreted as a declaration of a function whose name is `b` which:

- Returns an object of type `B`.
- Takes a (pointer to a) function as a parameter (the name of the parameter is not provided) that returns an object of type `A`.

So it **will** interpreted as a declaration be cause it **can** be interpreted as a such.

Comment: But how can it be a function declaration? (have slightly modified my question.)

Comment: @FrankPuffer I've updated my answer